# Коллбеки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, инспекция-кода

Никак не могу разобраться с коллбеками проверьте код пожалуйста:

```
let students = ''
function some(callback) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= group.data.length; i++){
        students = students + group.data[i].name + '\n'
        console.log(i)
    }
    callback()
}
some(function () {
    console.log('Done')
})
```

Comment: Стоит добавить в метки к вопросу **код ревью**. Все будет работать. В конце будет выведено **Done**. Только в **i <= group.data.length** вероятно требуется строгое условие **i < group.data.length**, потому что d data индексация идет от 0 и до data.length-1.

Comment: @tilin может быть, ответ напишете?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ответ, к сожадению, написать не смогу, потому как вопрос закрыт.